# Converting little-endian to ASCII

Tags: string, hex, ascii, endianness

I need help converting the little-endian string

```
8989d0261ee17bbf95ea5596711538b0
```

to ASCII. Can someone guide me through this process?

I'm not sure if this is correct, but I believe that I can convert this string into decimal by doing:

8 * 16^(string length) + 9 * 16^(string length - 1) + ... + 0 * 16^0

(multiplying the value of the string by it's place). Then once I get that, I subtract 2^32, and I will get the equivalent in decimal. Then, I can use an online converter to convert the decimal number to ASCII. Would this work?

Comment: I follow the "multiplying the value of the string by its place" part but after that, I'm lost. We'd love to help. Please [edit] with an example or expanded explanation. Also, please tag with a programming language, if applicable.

Comment: I think I'm supposed to subtract 2^32 because that's what I recall reading somewhere online. Should I not do this?

Comment: I'm guessing that's related to converting an unsigned integer to a 2's complement signed integer. Due to the number of bits that should be 2^128. But I'm still not following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

If you have a number, say 259, in base 10, the number can be rewritten as

2 * 10^2 + 5 * 10^1 + 9 * 10^0.

Similarly, in the example that you have above, each character in the string is assigned a value (similar to hexadecimal). I see that you have the conversion part correct from your equation. **Two's complement** is an operation on binary numbers, and is used in the representation of signed numbers. Following this methodology, we must subtract 2^32 to attain the equivalent value in decimal.

Note that similar reverse operations can also be performed to achieve the ASCII representation (in case you are unable to use a converter).

Here is a link that has many examples, which may be of interest to you: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html